# Migrate data from PostgreSQL to MongoDB

Tags: java, node.js, mongodb, postgresql, database-migration

I have to migrate 5 million records from `PostgreSQL` to `MongoDb`.

I tried using `mongify` for the same but as it runs on `ruby` and I am not at all acquainted with ruby i couldn't solve the errors posed by it.

So, I tried writing a code myself in `node.js` that would first convert `PostgreSQL data` into `JSON` and then insert that JSON into `mongoDb`.
But, this failed as it ate a lot of RAM and not more than 13000 records could be migrated.

Then I thought of writing code in `Java` because of its garbage collector. It works fine in terms of RAM utilization but the speed is very slow (around 10000 records/hour). At this rate it would take me days to migrate my data.

So, Is there a more efficient and faster way of doing this? Would a python program be faster than the Java program? Or is there any other ready-made tool available for doing the same?

My system configuration is :
  OS - Windows 7 (64 bit), 
  RAM - 4GB,
  i3 processor

Comment: are you using bulkInsert?http://www.thejavageek.com/2015/07/08/mongodb-bulk-insert/

Comment: @RahulKumar No I am fetching rows from Postgresql and inserting in Mongodb one by one. As converting all 5 million records together in JSON is not supported by the RAM. 
So, I am doing db.collection.insert(jsondata)

Comment: so you get all the 5 million rows from postgresql at once and then makes an entry into mongodb one by one? in any case you may look for batch processing.

Comment: @RahulKumar - No, I cannot get all 5 million rows from postgresql at once as RAM gets full. I am fetching the rows one by one. by using this query- 
 `select * from table_name limit 1 offset i` and I iterate `i` from 0 to 5 million.

Comment: You could read records from pg by let's say 200 each ( depends on size of records). convert these, do bulkInsert . And then do this with multiple threads at the same time ?

Comment: I think you can create a batch of 1000 records by using skip and limit in postgresql and process those 1000 and then use bulkinsert on those 1000 and do this batch process in loop until all the records are done. Most of the time is consumed for making connections to postgresql and mongodb. java is inherently faster.

Comment: same logic can be applied in nodejs, I remember for running  a script I was hitting the limit of 100MB of cursor in mongoDB. I ran in batch of 10000 inside a while loop to keep the memory issue at bay. I understand your issue is different since you have to get from one db and process before putting it. but bottom line remains same.

Comment: @RahulKumar - running the data in batches is working completely fine Thanks a ton.

Comment: glad, it helped. :)

Comment: Not that it will help you, but moving from PostgreSQL into MondoDB is a terrible-terrible idea. I know people who have dane it, and everyone ended up regretting it.

Answer (score 6):

Seems like I am late to the party. However, this might come in handy to somebody, someday!!!!

The following python-based migration framework should come in handy.

https://github.com/datawrangl3r/pg2mongo

Answering to your performance, the migration of each JSON object will be dynamic and there shouldn't be any memory lock issues when you use the above framework.

Hope it helps!!