# Migrate Postgres to MongoDB row-by-row

Tags: python, mongodb, postgresql, pymongo, psycopg2

I'm working on a project where I need to migrate from Postgres to MongoDB. The issue is,  I cannot save the entire Postgres database to memory. Also, unlike approaches taken [here](https://medium.com/containerum/how-we-migrated-data-from-postgresql-to-mongodb-6211886c5944) or [here](https://medium.com/@LarsKumbier/how-to-migrate-postgresql-to-mongodb-27d18fc22cb7), this is not a one-time migration, so I can't copy the entire contents of the Postgres database as text on disk every time data is transferred between the databases.

I was wondering if there was some way to "stream" data, row by row, from Postgres into MongoDB--realy, from`psycopg2` to `pymongo`.

**edit:** I suppose I should make the question more specific; I'm asking whether there exists a python library that can stream data between SQL/NoSQL databases, preferably one that works well with `psycopg2` and `pymongo`.

**edit2** For those who plan on down-voting, could you leave a comment explaining why? I thought it was a pretty legitimate question.

Comment: Have you considered using the [MongoDB FDW](https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mongo_fdw) to push data from PostgreSQL to MongoDB?

Comment: First time I've heard of it, thanks! Although I don't believe I have access to install new packages on the mongo server. I'll definitely look into that though.

Comment: You'd install it on the PostgreSQL server, hook up MongoDB collections as foreign tables, and then you could say things like `insert into some_mongo_collection (...) select ... from postgresql_table where ...`. I haven't used it but worth a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To anyone else looking for a solution, I found a python library that might help. This [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41997999/migrate-data-from-postgresql-to-mongodb) asked a similar question to mine, but the author was looking for node.js or java libraries for migration from Postgres to Mongo. However, one of the respondents linked to this python library: [pg2mongo: A hassle-free postresql to mongo migration framework.](https://github.com/datawrangl3r/pg2mongo)